# Stop ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseout from triggering on inner elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an unordered list where each li is a fixed small size but when you hover over it, it will expand to full size.  This is done via ng-mouseover and ng-mouseout.  The problem is that some of the li text contains other markup ( for example) and when the mouse enters the  tag, it triggers a mouseout event and collapses the li.

Obviously the desired behavior is to have the li remain enlarged while the mouse is inside it, even if it's over a child element.  Does anyone have an idea on how to basically ignore the mouseover of an inner element?  I would also need to ignore the mouseout of the li if it were going into a child element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two choices:

1. Use CSS [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events) on your inner elements (but first check how well it is supported in your target browsers).
2. Use ngMouseenter/ngMouseleave instead (See this [plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/cUgFOa4E5fp2m28iJU2o) for different behavior between mouseenter/mouseleave vs. mouseover/mouseout)

Comment: ng-mouseleave was the key, thanks a ton.  For those interested, there is a good video on mouseenter mouseleave vs mouseover mouseout at [this blog](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1805-jQuery-Events-MouseOver-MouseOut-vs-MouseEnter-MouseLeave.htm).

Comment: mouseleave totally fixed it for me too.